# Правильное получение данных из сессий и куки

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

Есть корзина в интернет-магазине. Товар в нее добавляется либо с помощью сессий, либо через куки. Бэк написан на php. Изначально была мысль сделать ajax запрос на бэк, чтобы получить данные из `$_COOKIE`, но понимаю, что куки и через js можно достать.

Правильно ли я понимаю, если я буду записывать товары в корзину через куки, то мне можно не взаимодействовать с бэком, вытаскивая данные из куки браузера, а если через сессии, то это уже будет только через ajax на бэкэнд?

Comment: А если все выбранные товары в куки не поместятся? ;)

Comment: @Visman это же сколько товаров туда нужно положить?))))

Comment: Сколько товаров вы уместите в 4 килобайта?

Comment: Я думаю вагон :), если использовать ID

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov +1, делать пару ID:количество и все в записи

Answer (score 1):

```js
// возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Далее можете разбирать то, что получили из куки (примера хранения не описано, поэтому более развернуто подсказать не могу)

более подробно можно почитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

готовая библиотека, с расширенным и удобным функционалом
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: поправил, описал функцию возврата куки в сообщении